# Parameter is not passed from child to parent

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass a parameter from the child module to the parent module constructor but for some reasons the parameter is not passed to the parent.

This is the child module:

```
var Child = (function()
{
    /**
     * @constructor
     */
    var Child = function(offer)
    {
        _Parent.call(this, offer);
    };

    /**
     * Prototype.
     */
    Child.prototype = Object.create(_Parent.prototype);
    Child.prototype.construct = Child;

    return Child;
}());
```

And the following is the parent:

```
var _Parent = (function()
{
    /**
     * Contains the offer data.
     *
     * @type {{}}
     */
    var offerData = {};

    /**
     * @construct
     */
    var _Parent = function(offer)
    {
        offerData = offer;
    };

    /**
     * Get the offer price.
     *
     * @param offering Index of the offering of which the price should be returned.
     */
    var getPrice = function(offering)
    {
        if(typeof offering == 'undefined')
        {
            offering = 0;
        }

        return offerData[offering]['Prices']['PriceRow']['TotalPriceInclVAT'];
    };

    /**
     * Prototype.
     */
    _Parent.prototype = {
        construct : _Parent,
        getPrice  : getPrice
    };

    return _Parent;
}());
```

I'm trying the `getPrice()` function on the child like this:

```
var child = new Child(offers);
child.getPrice();
```

but I receive always `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined` inside the *getPrice* function whenever i try to return the data.

Comment: Are you sure `offers` isn't `undefined`?

Comment: I think the error you got is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined`. This is what I got when I copied you code.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Just re-checked and I can confirm that `offers` is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure `offers` isn't `undefined`?

Another problem is that `offerData` isn't an instance property but a variable inside a closure where the `Parent` constructor is defined. When you create a new instance, it will override `offerData` in the closure, wiping out whatever was defined by the previous instantiation.

It's the same as doing this:

```js
var foo = {};

function Parent(bar){
  foo = bar;
}

Parent.prototype.getFoo = function(){
  return foo;
}

function Child(bar){
  Parent.call(this, bar);
}

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);

var hello = new Parent('Hello');
console.log(hello.getFoo()); // Hello

var world = new Child('World');
console.log(world.getFoo()); // World
console.log(hello.getFoo()); // World... wut???
```

This can be remedied by putting `offerData` as an instance property so it attaches *per instance*. You can always resort to pseudo-privates (prefix `_` by convention) if you want to keep the concept of privacy.

```
var _Parent = function(offer){
  this._offerData = offer;
};
```

Comment: You are right, the problem was exactly the second one you described (`offerData` declared inside a closure). Just so I understand it: if `_Parent` was declared inside an object instead of a closure it would have worked, right?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you defined `_Parent` only after you defined `Child`.
You need to first define `_Parent` and then the `Child` because the Child uses the parent in the line

```
Child.prototype = Object.create(_Parent.prototype)
```

I tested it, and it worked.

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting? And can you see what line of code is giving the error?